# Landscape Dedicated Server 15.11: Virtual Machines registering as computers

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, landscape, license, container

After upgrading LDS from 15.01 to 15.11, my virtual-machine licensed KVM instances are showing up as registered computers instead of virtual machines.

When I try to re-register the machine it also comes up under registered computers. This is causing me to exceed the free 10 licenses and I am not able to use any of the 50 container licenses. If I try to switch the license type in Landscape from the console I get the error message:

```
computer cannot be associated with a virtual machine license.
```

But it is a virtual machine. The licensing did work correctly when I was using ver 15.01 LDS. I also tried registering a new KVM VM from scratch and it also comes up as a computer. Here is my license info from the main web page:

```
Account name:   standalone
Registered computers:   15
Remaining full registrations:   0
Registered virtual machines:    0
Remaining virtual machine registrations:    0
Registered containers:  0
Remaining container registrations:  50
Registration key:   No registration key is required.
Created at:     Fri 11 Sep 2015, 13:16 EDT
```

Comment: LDS? 15.01? 15.11? The last Ubuntu LTS release is 14.04. There is no 15.11 or 15.01 version of Ubuntu, nor is there any LDS.

Comment: Did you mean "LTS" and 15.04 and 15.10?

Comment: @Zacharee1 [OPL - On Premise Landscape (formerly known as LDS)](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/?action=show&redirect=LDS)

Comment: LDS is Landscape Dedicated Server. The question is perfectly valid and the version numbers match Landscape releases.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour. The free license that we give out was always intended to be 10 free full metal computers and enough containers for the Autopilot to deploy OpenStack on those computers. We tightened that up in 15.11.

If you want to use Landscape with more than 10 total VMs and computers you need to [talk to us](https://landscape.canonical.com/contact-us) to buy more seats

Comment: The problem is the virtual machines are not falling under the virtual machines licensing count anymore, the are falling under the real servers license count. It was sorted out fine before the upgrade. I am just trying to get back to where I was before.

Comment: You don't have any VM licenses, so VMs will then take a full seat.

Comment: This was the license info before the upgrade to 15.11, when I was on 15.01Expiration date  Seats used  Seats free  License type
Never  5  5  Full
Never  10  0  Virtual - So the license model changed, that's all you had to say. Instead of all this run around. Thanks! I had 5 full licenses with 5 available and 10 virtual with none available. Pretty simple, I thought.

Comment: I don't know how else to phrase it. You do not have the licenses to use Landscape with > 10 (full machines + VMs)

Comment: I don't know how to rephrase that I was fine before the upgrade, license wise. So either you changed the model. Or the data is going into the wrong place to count the licenses.

Comment: Ok :) is it clear now? The license we give for free changed, that's why you hit this problem.

Comment: @AdamCollard - Wait, so the VM licenses can't be used for VMs anymore? Fuuuuuuuck, I can't upgrade anymore,

Comment: @FakeName VM licenses can, and will be, used for VMs. If a VM license is not available, it will use a Full license.Between 15.01 and 15.11 we replaced the *free* VM licenses with container licenses.

Comment: @AdamCollard - Well, whatever you want to call it, upgrading from 15.01 to the latest basically fucked my installation (3 physical hosts, 15 VMs), so I'm not exactly enthused. The fact that there's no sane way to just buy licenses doesn't help, either (no, I can't afford >$100/year for *each* VM for my home projects).

Comment: As in, this is just a few servers in my closet at my house. $100/year for *everything* (50 phys, 50 VMs, no support, seems reasonable off the top of my head) would probably be OK, but even that seems like a bit excessive (I rent a dedicated server for less then that yearly!). I don't need support, I don't care about ubuntu advantage or W/E, I just want central patch management. Canonical seems to have literally no provisions for anything *but* enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

To clear up any confusion it appears that the 10 licences are for bare metal servers OR VM servers

The 50 Containers refers to LXD containers only as defined here https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/lxd and again seems to exclude Docker containers.